# Dynamically insert R output in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, r

I have almost no experience with SQL statements, so I apologize for the potential ignorance of this question.  However, let's say I have an SQL table `results` which has the column fields of `b1 b2 b3 b4` and I have R output `dat` that corresponds to these values which looks like:

```
print(dat)
b1  b2  b3  b4
7   8   7   1
```

So I could run an SQL statement that looks something like:

```
a<-paste("INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`,`b2`,`b3`,`b4`) VALUES ","(",dat$b1,",",dat$b2,",",dat$b3,",",dat$b4",")",";",sep="")
for(i in(1:length(b))){
query(b[i])
}
```

Which works correctly; however, this is not dynamic, as `dat` (i.e., the R output) will not always contain all of the column values found in `results` (i.e., the database column fields), though the output will never have columns that are not found in the data-base column fields (e.g., in this case `dat` will never have a `b5` column).  I am trying dynamically write the code so that I don't have to write out all the `dat` columns and `results` column name fields in the code, and put `dat` into `results` so that regardless of the order, columns in `dat` will go into the corresponding columns fields in `results`, finally if a column value is missing in `dat` an NA will go into the corresponding column field in `results`.  For example if `dat` looked like:

```
print(dat)
b4  b1
7   8
```

`results` would look like:

```
b1  b2  b3  b4
8   NA  NA  7
```

Thank you!

Comment: if dat does not contain a column the value returned will be NULL. e.g. dat$b2 and dat$b3 will return NULL, can this be used instead of NA?

Comment: Yes NULL is completely fine.

Comment: Then your query should work for every situation. Didn't you try that?

Comment: Again, I am trying to do it so I don't have to write out all of column names in `dat` and all of the column name fields in `results` so my current code does not solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parameterize it in a pretty straightforward manner (and you can wrap the functionality below into a function for easier use):

```
dat <- mtcars

inserts <- sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s);",
        "results",
        paste(sprintf("`%s`", colnames(dat)), collapse=", "),
        sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) {
          paste(sprintf("`%s`", unlist(dat[i,], use.names=FALSE)) , collapse=", ")
        }))

head(inserts)
## [1] "INSERT INTO `results` (`mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`) VALUES (`21`, `6`, `160`, `110`, `3.9`, `2.62`, `16.46`, `0`, `1`, `4`, `4`);"    
## [2] "INSERT INTO `results` (`mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`) VALUES (`21`, `6`, `160`, `110`, `3.9`, `2.875`, `17.02`, `0`, `1`, `4`, `4`);"   
## [3] "INSERT INTO `results` (`mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`) VALUES (`22.8`, `4`, `108`, `93`, `3.85`, `2.32`, `18.61`, `1`, `1`, `4`, `1`);"  
## [4] "INSERT INTO `results` (`mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`) VALUES (`21.4`, `6`, `258`, `110`, `3.08`, `3.215`, `19.44`, `1`, `0`, `3`, `1`);"
## [5] "INSERT INTO `results` (`mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`) VALUES (`18.7`, `8`, `360`, `175`, `3.15`, `3.44`, `17.02`, `0`, `0`, `3`, `2`);" 
## [6] "INSERT INTO `results` (`mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, `hp`, `drat`, `wt`, `qsec`, `vs`, `am`, `gear`, `carb`) VALUES (`18.1`, `6`, `225`, `105`, `2.76`, `3.46`, `20.22`, `1`, `0`, `3`, `1`);"
dat <- iris

inserts <- sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s);",
        "results",
        paste(sprintf("`%s`", colnames(dat)), collapse=", "),
        sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) {
          paste(sprintf("`%s`", unlist(dat[i,], use.names=FALSE)) , collapse=", ")
        }))

head(inserts)
## [1] "INSERT INTO `results` (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`) VALUES (`5.1`, `3.5`, `1.4`, `0.2`, `1`);"
## [2] "INSERT INTO `results` (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`) VALUES (`4.9`, `3`, `1.4`, `0.2`, `1`);"  
## [3] "INSERT INTO `results` (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`) VALUES (`4.7`, `3.2`, `1.3`, `0.2`, `1`);"
## [4] "INSERT INTO `results` (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`) VALUES (`4.6`, `3.1`, `1.5`, `0.2`, `1`);"
## [5] "INSERT INTO `results` (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`) VALUES (`5`, `3.6`, `1.4`, `0.2`, `1`);"  
## [6] "INSERT INTO `results` (`Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, `Species`) VALUES (`5.4`, `3.9`, `1.7`, `0.4`, `1`);"

set.seed(1492)
dat <- data.frame(b1=sample(10, 10),
                  b2=sample(10, 10),
                  b3=sample(10, 10),
                  b4=sample(10, 10))

inserts <- sprintf("INSERT INTO `%s` (%s) VALUES (%s);",
        "results",
        paste(sprintf("`%s`", colnames(dat)), collapse=", "),
        sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) {
          paste(sprintf("`%s`", unlist(dat[i,], use.names=FALSE)) , collapse=", ")
        }))

head(inserts)
## [1] "INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) VALUES (`3`, `7`, `7`, `2`);" 
## [2] "INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) VALUES (`2`, `6`, `4`, `9`);" 
## [3] "INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) VALUES (`9`, `2`, `2`, `7`);" 
## [4] "INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) VALUES (`1`, `4`, `5`, `10`);"
## [5] "INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) VALUES (`7`, `10`, `1`, `6`);"
## [6] "INSERT INTO `results` (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) VALUES (`6`, `9`, `10`, `4`);"
```

But, there may be more optimal ways of shoving this data back into a database if we knew more abt the problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but I can't quite get it to work.  When I query `inserts` I get the following error: `Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :could not run statement: Unknown column '-0.0366528160' in 'field list'` That value is from the first column, so it looks like it thinks that is the column name.  Any thoughts?  Thank you

Comment: I have no idea what database you're using, how the schema is setup or the SQL syntax it accepts. I was just working with the example you provided.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I will look into the specific syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if you have a huge database, but an easy fix is just to read the dataset into R, append a dataset (for example, using `dplyr::bind_rows`), and then write the whole thing out again.

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dplyr)

con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "test")
con %>%
  dbReadTable("results") %>%
  bind_rows(dat) %>%
  dbWriteTable(con, "results", . , overwrite = TRUE)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Or

```
con %>% dbWriteTable("results", dat, append = TRUE)
```

To create the table,

```
con %>% dbWriteTable("results", dat)
```

Comment: So how exactly would this look?

Comment: Yeah I probably don't want to read the entire database into R every time, and I can't get this solution to work.  I am assuming it is because I don't currently have data in the database table, and it looks like this solution assumes data already exists there.

Comment: There is also an append option in dbWriteTable but it might not work if you want to add to columns that don't exist yet (definitely try it out though). The first time you write out the table, just do `dbWriteTable(con, "results", dat)`

Comment: Thank you for the info, definitely useful!